# What is "a ransom" as it appears in 1 Timothy 2:6?

Tags: word-study

1 Timothy 2:5-6. "For there is one God, and there is one mediator between God and men, the man Christ Jesus, 6 who gave himself as a ransom for all,...". ESV

If a prisoner is in a jail and a ransom is paid so that they can go free, what is there to stop them going free?

If a ransom has been paid "for all" will not all walk out and go free?

Does a ransom paid guarantee freedom?

Comment: If the efficacy of said ransom would not have been mediated by faith in Jesus as the Christ, Paul, who wrote these words, would never have bothered spreading or preaching Christianity in the first place.

Comment: @Lucian - what about the apostle John who said that only those who believe in Jesus, as the Son of God, could be saved (John 3:16)?

Comment: What if He wants to offer us more than just getting out of jail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is “a ransom” as it appears in 1 Timothy 2:6?

First, let's look at what Greek word is being used. In *Vine's Expository Dictionary* under the section "[Additional Notes](https://fliphtml5.com/pcdj/ioku/basic/1599)", gives an interesting explanation for the word *antilytron* used at 1 Timothy:

> Of special doctrinal importance are Matt. 20:28; Mark 10:45, “to give His life a ransom (*lutron*) for (*anti*) many.” Here the substitutionary significance, “instead of,” is clear, as also with the compound *antilutron* in 1 Tim. 2:6, “who gave Himself a ransom (*antitutron*) for (*huper*) all”; here the use of *huper*, “on behalf of,” is noticeable. Christ gave Himself as a ransom (of a substitutionary character), not instead of all men, but on behalf of *all*.

A footnote in reference to 1 Tim. 2:6, gives additional insight to the word *antilytron*:

> The Greek word here used, *an·tiʹly·tron*, appears nowhere else in the Bible. It is related to the word that Jesus used for ransom (*lyʹtron*) at Mark 10:45. However, *The New International Dictionary of New Testament Theology* points out that *an·tiʹly·tron* ‘accentuates the notion of exchange.’ Appropriately, the *New World Translation* renders it “corresponding ransom.”

So what do we learn from these two references? That Jesus' ransom is not just the 'payment' but also the conduit by which we can be redeemed from our sinful state.

**If a prisoner is in a jail and a ransom is paid so that they can go free, what is there to stop them going free? If a ransom has been paid "for all" will not all walk out and go free?**

As crazy as it may sound, there are some prisoners that **don't** want to be free. There are two reasons for this:

1. They don't want to deal with the problems and responsibilities that they had prior to incarceration and choose to stay in prison (hence the reason for reoffending)
2. They are so comfortable in the fact that they are given food, clothing and shelter that they would rather enjoy their laidback prison life.

**Does a ransom paid guarantee freedom?**

No. Paul tells us:

- "Keep working out your own salvation with fear and trembling.” (Philippians 2:12 *NWT*)
- “If we practice sin willfully after having received the accurate knowledge of the truth, there is no longer any sacrifice for sins left.”​ (Hebrews 10:​26; see also Hebrews 6:4-6 *NWT*)

For additional information on Jesus' ransom sacrifice see the following articles:

- [How Is Jesus’ Sacrifice “a Ransom for Many”?](https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/jesus-sacrifice-ransom/)
- [The Ransom​—God’s Greatest Gift](https://www.jw.org/en/library/books/bible-teach/the-ransom-jesus-sacrifice/) from *What Does the Bible Really Teach?*
- [The Ransom—A “Perfect Present” From the Father](https://www.jw.org/en/library/magazines/watchtower-study-february-2017/jesus-ransom-a-perfect-present/)

Answer (score 1):

Mark 10:45
New International Version

> For even the Son of Man did not come to be served, but to serve, and to give his life as a **ransom** for many."

[as] a ransom
λύτρον (**lytron**)
Noun - Accusative Neuter Singular
Strong's 3083: From luo; something to **loosen** with, i.e. A redemption price.

1 Timothy 2:6

> who gave himself as a **ransom** for all people. This has now been witnessed to at the proper time.

[as] a ransom
ἀντίλυτρον (antilytron)
Noun - Accusative Neuter Singular
Strong's 487: A ransom. From **anti** and **lutron**; a redemption-price.

Jamieson-Fausset-Brown Bible Commentary

> The Greek implies not merely ransom, but a **substituted** or **equivalent** ransom: the Greek preposition, "anti," implying reciprocity and **vicarious** substitution.

What is “a ransom” as it appears in 1 Timothy 2:6?

It is not the usual simple ransom but a vicarious substitutionary ransom.

If a prisoner is in a jail and a ransom is paid so that they can go free, what is there to stop them going free?

Unbelief.

If a ransom has been paid "for all" will not all walk out and go free?

Only if he believes.

Does a ransom paid guarantee freedom?

if he believes.